# Use dynamic site URLs in WordPress posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm in the process of making a WordPress blog, and I have to change the site URL frequently for testing. Is there an efficient way to dynamically insert the blog's current home URL into posts?

E.g. I want to do something like this:

```
[button link="[current_site_url]/about/" size="large"]About[/button]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>` is what you look for...

Also you can get url to template directory with

`<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`

TO see other parameters of bloginfo please refer to ;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

```
//All these functions return the blog's URL as configured in Settings 
site_url(); // Does not display the URL
get_bloginfo('url'); // Does not display the URL
bloginfo('url'); // Always displays the URL

// Returns the root directory URL 
// For http://example.com/myblog returns http://example.com 
home_url(); // Does not display the URL
```